# How to prevent from opening an duplicated layout?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Picture 1. This is my create_layout.

[image]

Picture 2. This is my custom contact list when I clicked on add member button.

[image]

Picture 3. NOW HERE IS THE PROBLEM. When press on the select button. I wanted to list the chosen contact value back to my first image layout. But it is opening a duplicate of my first layout and appearing there.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("............"+ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)
                {
                if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {
                     checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                     checkedcontacts.append("\n"); 

                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("..Not Checked......"+name1.get(i).toString());
                }

            }     

            Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), CreateTab.class);
            i.putExtra("str",checkedcontacts.toString());
            startActivity(i);
            finish();                    
        }       
    });
```

I know the problem is that I make an intent so that when user clicks on select button, it will point back to CreateTab class which will repeat the onCreate. But how can I prevent from the onCreate again?

Comment: you can't prevent activity form loading onCreate Method. but you can do one thing that you can open activity with SINGLE_TASK flag so that it will load activity from history stack and does not create new instance.

Comment: you can use startactivityForresult in your case i think

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Is there any example on opening activity with SINGLE_TASK flag or startactivityForeesult?

Comment: i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should you use onActivityResult() method to read the returned result.

Do this in your CreateTab.class

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddMember.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 100); // 100 is some code to identify the returning result
```

Method to read the result from newly created activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
         String str = data.getExtras().get("str");
    }
}
```

Send result back to old activity when StartActivityForResult() is used

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("str", checkedcontacts.toString());

// Setting resultCode to 100 to identify on old activity
setResult(100,i);
```

and close your AddMember activity

```
finish()
```

so your click event should look like this;

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("............"+ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)
                {
                if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {
                     checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                     checkedcontacts.append("\n"); 

                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("..Not Checked......"+name1.get(i).toString());
                }

            }     

              Intent i = new Intent();
              i.putExtra("str", checkedcontacts.toString());

              // Setting resultCode to 100 to identify on old activity
              setResult(100,i);
              finish();
        }       
    });
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Hi. Thanks. (int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data). It said there is misplaced construct.

Comment: @EtAndrea in CreateTab.class right click->Source-> overwrite/implemetn methods
find onActivityResult and add this event to your class.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. Just another small problem, data.getExtras().get("str"); cannot convert from object to string in my CreateTab.class

Comment: use  data.getExtras().getString("str")

Comment: Please have a look at my gist. I follow your code exactly, there is no error, but nothing appear after I clicked on the button. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aea19b2be9af9519bbb3

Comment: @EtAndrea whıch button? Select button on the AddMember?

Comment: Yes. I call it add_button

Comment: you have to post your CreateTab.class. as i see you are doing nothing with your data which you get from AddMember.class "data.getExtras().getString("str");"

Answer (score 0):

Don't start previous activity again, just update selector Activity's result, and call `finish()`.

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, PreviousActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("selection",checkedcontacts.toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK,resultIntent);
    finish();
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks. but new Intent(this, PreviousActivity.class) is undefined. Why is that so?

Comment: @EtAndrea Make sure you call it inside the Activity, or supply a `Context` as its first argument. The second argument is the class of activity you want to send results to. `PreviousActivity` is an example name I used.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. There is no error now. But still not working, please refer and help me. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/27e67c91f9d6fa8e4f2c